# How to print a javascript object from highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to output the value (month12 revenue - month12 cost) at the very bottom of the chart where it says "ROI: $XXX.XX or X%". I am new with JS and every function I have wrote doesn't work. How can I make the calculation (referenced above) print to the bottom of the chart?

This should make it easier to see what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/nlem33/L5cY6/9/

```
console.log(newdata);

chart.series[0].setData(newdata2);
chart.series[1].setData(newdata);
```

Comment: What is your question about a programming language or tool? "It doesn't seem to be working" is not a question about a programming language or tool.

Comment: Your right sorry about that, I rephrased the question above. The question pertains to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost close.

The reason the graph was not changing is because of `yAxis -` **max 60000**

Try reducing it and check what happens . The values that you were using `were not to scale` properly.

So you need to set the min and max based on the user selection and redraw the chart every time the value exceeds the maximum.

While caluculating the newdata have a max value and pass that value when you are redrawing the chart so that it can be accounted for.